# Azure VM Creation is Stuck at Installing Extensions

Tags: azure

Last week I deleted everything in my portal. Every affinity group, DNS server, vnet, storage account, virtual machine and cloud services.

When I wanted to start over again, I am not able to create a virtual machine as it gets stuck at installing extensions. I can RDP to the server fine but there are error logs saying DNS could not be resolved.

A few notes:

1. I can RDP to the server using computername\username
2. Disks I attach to the server is not visible in the server
3. Changing locations doesn't help.
4. I am provisioning Microsoft images from the gallery.

Answer (score 3):

I found a fix to this I hit restart on the VM while it still said installing extensions and closed out the window that the azure page was open in then opened up a new window re-logged back into the azure portal and the machine magically was working.

Comment: seems the api response is very slow and what we see on portal as status is sometime misleading. Hence, I am voting this answer as useful.